# Rootstock (for Salesforce) Support

Tags: administration, documentation, help, rootstock, third-party

Does anyone know of any resources that support the **ERP/MRP product Rootstock** *inside Salesforce* beyond their "Customer Resource Center"?

- no Community/etc on their website;
- almost nothing (currently) on StackExchange;
- SF Dev site has two articles even loosely related (1 they cannot get triggers to work due to RS, 1 is RS looking for a Dev)

Google searches yield nothing useful.  Help!  #Rootstock #ERP #MRP  The key is that we're talking about **Rootstock FOR SALESFORCE**.  Thanks!

Comment: I worked with them quite a bit, very bad experience. Do you have specific question ?

Comment: I remember they do have a community created by other clients you should definitely ask them to give you the link. Sorry I can't find it.

Comment: "specific question"   :-)   That's like asking .... never mind.  I have many MANY questions, and have to rely upon 1 specific person (an outside contractor) and then a couple more (not clear if they are outside or inside RS).  If you've worked with RS for SF, you likely know what I mean.   In any case, this thing is a giant black-box with no training, no architectural diagrams showing the relationship between it's (currently) 546 objects and SF-proper, and many of the (unsearchable) PDFs in their Resource Center show "** SOON TO BE uPDATED **" with a date of months to 1.5 years ago.....

Comment: ....two documents are actually empty except for a date (months ago) and a "** SOON TO COME **" comment.    It is extremely annoying to see a product with such a wide mix of good, bad and downright frustrating.  It does so many things well, but has SO many shortcomings -- and it's TRYING to be a solution "for everyone" so it's already bloatware on every level.   :-(

Comment: This is why the Question is fairly "generic" as opposed to "anyone know how to insert a Quote into the SOAPI without blah blah blah".

Comment: I worked for a year with this product. Everything you said remind me exactly what I experienced. My client was getting help from Salesforce to get rid of the product.

Comment: Yes, well, my Project Manager "at" Rootstock has now said:   "Rootstock does not at this time have any Rootstock-supported or Rootstock-monitored forums; we cannot provide direction to forums of unknown origin, management or validity."   Oh well.

Comment: There is definitely a forum they just don't like their clients to talk to each other. I will provide you the link on Monday from someone who still work with this product.

Comment: I found what you were looking for the success community chatter group https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001vmT

Comment: OMG... that looks promising... and RECENT POSTS TOO.   Thanks SOOO much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would put that as a answer for other people :

[Salesforce Success Community for Rootstock (user-driven)](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001vmT)

Don't hesitate to put other question if you have specific questions. I remember doing a lot of development around rootstock using the SOAPI. There is a lot of hacks you can do ;-)

Comment: Well, my very first attempt to get something custom developed using their SOAPI documentation (actually the SOqAPI documentation) has already come to a standstill since it does not support populating CUSTOM fields - so, we're now planning on doing normal API calls to insert SO Line Items from our website.

Comment: I dont think you can insert /update so line. except custom fields, they called it hardened objects. So you might insert the soapi then update the sales order line created. However there is also a hack to update this restricted fields/objects by using the trigger option field on each object. If I remember if you set the value to {"ET":"1"}.

Comment: The other bug issue we faced was around security. They advised to their customers to make everything public because it's just unmanageable. It was a massive issue for our business because everybody could see everything.

Comment: Re:  SO Line Item insertion... it's a hardened object ("now?") so theoretically I can insert.  We'll see.

Comment: Re: Security... definitely going to ask about that, because that is essentially a DEAL KILLER if I'm not mistaken, and I would like to ASSume this is no longer an issue as Roles and Permissions have been a constant conversataion, but mainly with the third-party consultant who has not been fully reliable.  Ugh.  THANKS.